# How do I write an SQL query to identify duplicate values in a specific field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is the table I'm working with:

[image: The table]

I would like to identify only the ReviewIDs that have duplicate deduction IDs for different parameters.

For example, in the image above, ReviewID 114 has two different parameter IDs, but both records have the same deduction ID.

For my purposes, this record (ReviewID 114) has an error.  There should not be two or more unique parameter IDs that have the same deduction ID for a single ReviewID.

I would like write a query to identify these types of records, but my SQL skills aren't there yet.  Help?

Thanks!

**Update 1:** I'm using TSQL (SQL Server 2008) if that helps
**Update 2:** The output that I'm looking for would be the same as the image above, minus any records that do not match the criteria I've described.

Cheers!

Comment: So, in that image, the two 114 records should be present, as well as 5 instances of review_id 124?

Comment: @Ellesedil that's right, records 13 and 14 in that table show two different parameter IDs with the same deduction ID, so that would be one of the Review IDs I'd like to capture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT review_id, deduction_id FROM table
    GROUP BY review_id, deduction_id
    HAVING COUNT(parameter_id) > 1
) t2 ON t1.review_id = t2.review_id AND t1.deduction_id = t2.deduction_id;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d858f/3

If it is possible to have exact duplicates and that is ok, you can modify the HAVING clause to COUNT(DISTINCT parameter_id).

Comment: This answer provides the correct results.  I ended up using the CTE suggested by Michael L, since the table in the image is the result of yet another query, but this answer got me what I was looking for. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

```
Select ReviewID, deduction_ID from Table
Group By ReviewID, deduction_ID
Having count(ReviewID) > 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e113/3 has an example

Comment: This does nothing to take account for the parameter_id, which is necessary in order to determine if a review_id is in error or not.

Comment: If you made that `Having count(DISTINCT ReviewID) > 1` then you'd know if there were two different reviewId (rather than just the same one multiple times.

Comment: @Ellesedil, correct, the parameter ID needs to be taken into account.  Each deduction ID is unique, and can only be applied to a single parameter (ID).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the criteria:  For each combination of `ReviewID` and `deduction_id` you can have only one parameter_id and you want a query that produces a result *without* the ReviewIDs that break those rules (rather than identifying those rows that do).  This will do that:

```
;WITH review_errors AS (
  SELECT  ReviewID
  FROM test
  GROUP BY ReviewID,deduction_ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT parameter_id) > 1
)
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
  LEFT JOIN review_errors r
    ON t.ReviewID = r.ReviewID
WHERE r.ReviewID IS NULL
```

To explain: `review_errors` is a [common table expression](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/10/sql-server-common-table-expression-cte-and-few-observation/) (think of it as a named sub-query that doesn't clutter up the main query).  It selects the ReviewIDs that break the criteria.  When you left join on it, it selects all rows from the left table regardless of whether they match the right table and only the rows from the right table that match the left table.  Rows that do not match will have nulls in the columns for the right-hand table.  By specifying `WHERE r.ReviewID IS NULL` you eliminate the rows from the left hand table that match the right hand table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4dc10/1)

Comment: I think you have it backwards, as the OP indicates he wants to identify records such as review_id 114, which is an invalid record. Also, with logic you've written, you exclude all instances of a review_id, even if it has some records that are "good".

Comment: Fair enough - I could have misunderstood.  It's a trivial modification and [here's the SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4dc10/2)

Comment: You have to join on deduction_id too. Otherwise, you could be selecting good records from a review_id that has some bad records. I like the CTE, though.

Comment: If you [look here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39d73d/1) it will select _all_ records for a ReviewID that has at least one bad record.  However, if he wants to differentiate between good and bad records for the same ReviewID [joining on deduction_id](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31d5c/2) will let him do that.